# Fade transparent .png's on top of each other on clicking link

Tags: click, png, transparent, fade

I am creating a 650 X 610 px historical railway map and would like to start with a blank map, then fade in transparent .png layers containing just a fragment of the railway, one on top of the other, building up to an image of the whole network.

There would be a list of the dates the network was extended to click and make that bit of line appear. Easily done using solid images, but very slow and there are 31 images.

I couldn't find any forum queries about this anywhere.  Please could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple example (tested in Opera 10 and Firefox 2). Each image must be of the same dimension. Meaning that each layer is placed at the same location.

What you should change are:

- All `width` and `height` values (in pixels) within `<style>` block to match your complete map.
- The `layerdata` array, which contains an object for each layer's date selection text (`date`) and the URL of the image (`url`).
- `animdelay`. Delay in millisecond (<sup>1</sup>/<sub>1000</sub> second) unit per opacity level for fade in/out. The default is 100ms. There's a total of 10 opacity levels. Decrease the delay to speed up the animation.

`sample.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #dates label { display:block; }
      #frame { border:1px solid black; width:500px; height:500px; }
      .layer {
        "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
        filter:alpha(opacity=0);
        opacity:0; position:absolute; width:500px; height:500px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    Date:
    <div id="dates">
    </div>
    <div id="frame">
    </div>
    <script>
      //get element opacity for Internet Explorer
      function getOpacityIE(ele) { //returns level: 0-100
        return ele.filters[0].opacity;
      }
      //set element opacity for Internet Explorer
      function setOpacityIE(ele,level) { //level: 0-100
        ele.filters[0].opacity=level;
      }
      //get element opacity for web-standard browsers
      function getOpacityStd(ele) { //returns level: 0-100
        return (ele.style.opacity!=''?ele.style.opacity*100:0);
      }
      //set element opacity for web-standard browsers
      function setOpacityStd(ele,level) { //level: 0-100
        ele.style.opacity=(level/100).toFixed(1);
      }
      //fade in/out each layers based on target date index
      function animate() {
        var done=true;
        for (var i=0; i<layers.length; i++) {
          var adjust=i<=dateidx?10:-10;
          var level=getOpacity(layers[i]);
          if (((adjust>0)&&(level<100)) || ((adjust<0)&&(level>0))) {
           setOpacity(layers[i],level+adjust);
           done=false;
          }
        }
        if (!done) animtimer=window.setTimeout(animate,animdelay);
      }
      //set/update layer index to show/hide and animate it
      function setdate(ele) {
        window.clearTimeout(animtimer);
        dateidx=ele.attributes['index'].value*1;
        animate();
      }
      //add date selection, below any existing one
      function addselection(idx,date) {
        var a=document.createElement('LABEL');
        a.htmlFor='date'+idx;
        a.innerHTML='<input id="date'+idx+'" index="'+idx+'" name="date" type="radio" onclick="setdate(this)" /> '+date;
        dates.appendChild(a);
      }
      //add layer (image) into frame, on top of any existing one
      function addlayer(idx,url) {
        var a=document.createElement('IMG');
        a.className='layer';
        a.src=url;
        layers.push(a);
        frame.appendChild(a);
      }
      //layerdata: from bottom to top
      var layerdata=[
        {date:'2000-01-01', url:'image1.png'},
        {date:'2000-01-08', url:'image2.png'},
        {date:'2000-01-15', url:'image3.png'},
        {date:'2000-01-22', url:'image4.png'}
      ];
      //animation delay in 1/1000 second unit per opacity level
      var animdelay=100;
      //runtime variables
      var dateidx=-1;
      var layers=[];
      var animtimer=0;
      if (typeof(frame.style.opacity)!='undefined') {
        var getOpacity=getOpacityStd;
        var setOpacity=setOpacityStd;
      } else {
        var getOpacity=getOpacityIE;
        var setOpacity=setOpacityIE;
      }
      //generate date selections and layers
      for (var i=0; i<layerdata.length; i++) {
        addselection(i,layerdata[i].date);
        addlayer(i,layerdata[i].url);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thankyou Jay for going to all that trouble, but I copied and pasted the code, added the image addresses, and all I got was a black-bordered square with Date: above it. Kept the layerdata as you had written it, moved my image files into the same directory as the html file and just changed the filenames image1.png to 1854.png and so on. Life is not simple.

Comment: It works in Opera v10, but not in Firefox v2. So I fixed it. Sorry for that.

Comment: Thanks again, Jay. Worked beautifully in Opera and Chrome - exactly what I wanted (if anyone else is reading this, it's an extremely useful script)- but no dates or images in Firefox 13.01 and only showed dates and the last image in IE9. As this is way beyond my very limited capabilities, could you press on? Thankyou indeed.

Comment: I'll see what I can do. And thanks for telling me the specific browsers and versions which have problem running it. It's very useful.

Comment: I've updated the code to run on MSIE and newer Firefox. Tested with Firefox 14 and MSIE 8. I'm unable to install MSIE 9, so I can't test it. In MSIE 8, the transparency looks very ugly. Firefox, Opera, and most likely Google too, has much better transparency display.

Comment: You CLEVER THING!!! It's wonderful, just exactly what I wanted. I hope you go on to be rich and famous. Thankyou