# fade in images with javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Without using jquery, is it possible to simultaneously fadein and replace another image?

I've created a map with intricate polygonal areas that onmouseover and onmouseout, replaces imageA with imageB as seen in the following function. However, the transition is too abrupt upon replacing the image. It would be awesome if I can simply add a couple lines of code below the "if (aa==0) {...}" to do this. Unfortunately, my rudimentary knowledge of javascript prevents me from doing so.

```
aa=0;
function replaceImage()
{
if (aa==0) 
  {
  aa=1;
  document.getElementById('imageA').src="img/imageB.png";
  }
else
  {
  aa=0;
  document.getElementById('imageA').src="img/imageA.png";
  }
}
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: _"Without using jquery, is it possible to..."_ - Of course. jQuery can't do anything that isn't already possible in "plain" JavaScript... You'd want to use `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` to update the CSS opacity of the element(s) involved.

Comment: Check this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572128/fade-transparent-pngs-on-top-of-each-other-on-clicking-link

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can play around with loops and adjust the opacity of image to fade in and out. You might wanna look at this link if you are willing to user css3. http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

Comment: BE aware though - Opacity is very tricky. Jquery does a number of manipulations to make it work crossbrowser.

Comment: yeah, Opacity could be tricky sometimes ,and its a pain when you have to adjust z-index to make things look like you want to.

Comment: the problem with css is that I plan to overlay multiple images on top of one another and onmouseover (of a specific region in the "default image", reveal one of those images. css doesn't seem to work when working with areas and maps because they are not visible elements as I was told it's not a visible element